# Save a Command in Vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to save a command in vim? I want to be able to go straight to a directory after login, such as:

```
cd directory/subdirectory/files
```

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: I think this question should be rephrased, but I'm hesitant to just edit it myself because I might misinterpret the ambiguity.  Perhaps you mean "Automatically execute a command on startup" instead of "Save a command"?  And do you mean when you log in and get a shell, or within Vim when you start it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have your shell cd to a particular directory after *login*, then put this in your `~/.bashrc` (assuming you're using bash):

```
if [ shopt -q login_shell ]
then
    cd directory/subdirectory/files
fi
```

If you want to have `vim` cd to a particular directory each time you open it, then put this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
cd directory/subdirectory/files
```

Note that the `cd` in your `~/.vimrc` is not the shell's `cd` but is a Vim command. See

```
:help :cd
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only problem is that i have different directories on separate parts of the filesystem that i would like quick access to. Any ideas that might help me?

Comment: There are a lot of tools that can help with that. However, I'm not very familiar with many of them. From the command line, I like using `wcd` (http://wcd.sourceforge.net/). For within Vim, I've heard good things about FuzzyFinder (http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) and ctrlp (http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736). You can also use bash aliases to create commands for jumping to frequently-used directories, e.g., `alias cda='cd /long/path/to/dir'`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.vimrc`, you can define custom commands (like `:CdA`) that quickly switch to directories; e.g.:

```
:command! CdA cd directory/subdirectory/files
:command! CdB cd directory/other_directory/files
```